# Optimize way to drop big database table

Tags: database, sybase, sql-drop

I need to drop huge database table having 1.7 Billion records.

DB: Sybase, DB size: 350 gb.

I ran 'drop table' statement and its taking more than 18 hours.
Is there any other way to optimize it.

Comment: Does your RDMS support TRUNCATE. In sql server this command bypasses logging and just rearranges pointers and it is a snap executing in a few seconds.

Comment: Disregard my earlier answer. I thought you meant delete all records from a table in which case TRUNCATE would be preferred. I do not know which would be more performant a DROP or TRUNCATE DROP. DROP probably performs a TRUNCATE before all metadata is cleared. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: I don't know how sybase works, but in mysql you can delete those database files from the filesystem.

Comment: How about `DROP DATABASE`?

Comment: @ZoffDino No, I cant. Don't want to delete other tables

Comment: Is there something in the logs? can you post the log?

Comment: @OfirW Yeah. That's another issue. Due transaction logs, space is getting filled up.

Comment: If you want to keep the log  of the delete you shouldn´t use truncate because it is a minimally logged operation . In case you are running out of space use _disk resize _ on the device in which the log is mounted. There is a parameter equivalent to mysql innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit that waits certain time before saving the buffer log to the  file log I don´t remember right now which is the name but as soon as i remember I´ll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is too big for a comment. If it doesn't help I'll delete it. I found the following on a sybase forum ie make sure all foreign keys etc have been removed.

http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C4a3b0950.27df.1681692777@sybase.com%3E

> P.S. I found a workaround that consistently speeds up the table and
>   view drops: DROP FOREIGN KEYS from the database first. My script that
>   drops tables and views was previously taking 5 hours (about 20 seconds
>   to drop each object); if FKs are dropped first, it finishes in 20
>   minutes.

They did it for the whole database in your case you would need to do it for the table in question, I'm not sure this will help because the docs here

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X58548.htm

Actually say that foreign keys etc are automatically dropped in tables that reference the one you are dropping. Although it does not mention what happens if those keys are currently part of a running transaction when you call drop.